# Content > Design > Configuration Blank on new installation

Tags: magento2, theme, installation

I did a fresh setup of magento2 and upon completion, I couldn't set any configuration options in `Content > Design > Configuration`.  The table rendered with no available results.

After trying numerous troubleshooting steps, I finally deleted my custom theme out of the app/design/frontend/vendor/template folder.  Once `app/design/frontend/` only contained the `Magento` folder and nothing else, the install properly set a default configuration for the stores and the `Content > Design > Configuration` renders perfectly normal.  I am then able to copy my custom theme back into the frontend design folder and set it as active.

Apparently, Magento2 completely falls apart and can't set the default Luma theme if you have theme files installed.  Has anyone else encountered this bug?  Could there be something in my custom theme that causes a fresh install to fail when setting the default theme?

Comment: How you create a new theme?

Comment: I followed the file structure example from the dev docs here:  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

I set mine to extend `Magento/luma`

Comment: old post I know - but did you ever find a solution? suffering same thing  :S

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I think I had to completely remove the custom theme, perform the setup, and then add the theme folder back in afterward.

Comment: @DavidStillson I tried that and weirdly still an issue on Magento 2.2.1 :S but no worries will do some debugging, if I find a solution will let you know! Thanks anyways :)